# show empty records with date that don't have data

Tags: sql, t-sql

i have a SQL table, that show employees attendances like date,time,employee ID and key( in or out), as:

```
ID      AttTime     Key     attDate
123     08:00 AM    IN      2015-08-21
123     06:00 PM    OUT     2015-08-21
123     08:00 AM    IN      2015-08-22
123     06:00 PM    OUT     2015-08-22
123     08:00 AM    IN      2015-08-23
123     06:00 PM    OUT     2015-08-23
123     08:00 AM    IN      2015-08-24
123     06:00 PM    OUT     2015-08-24
123     08:00 AM    IN      2015-08-25
123     06:00 PM    OUT     2015-08-25
123     08:00 AM    IN      2015-08-26
123     06:00 PM    OUT     2015-08-26
123     08:00 AM    IN      2015-08-27
123     06:00 PM    OUT     2015-08-27
```

now i want to show all dates requested even if they don't have any data..
example: if the user request the report from 01-08-2015 TO 30-08-2015
I want the output to be like below:

```
ID      AttTime     Key     attDate

null    null        null    2015-08-01
null    null        null    2015-08-01
null    null        null    2015-08-02
null    null        null    2015-08-02
null    null        null    2015-08-03
null    null        null    2015-08-03
null    null        null    2015-08-04
null    null        null    2015-08-04
.
.
.
.
.
123     08:00 AM    IN      2015-08-21
123     06:00 PM    OUT     2015-08-21
123     08:00 AM    IN      2015-08-22
123     06:00 PM    OUT     2015-08-22
123     08:00 AM    IN      2015-08-23
123     06:00 PM    OUT     2015-08-23
123     08:00 AM    IN      2015-08-24
123     06:00 PM    OUT     2015-08-24
123     08:00 AM    IN      2015-08-25
123     06:00 PM    OUT     2015-08-25
123     08:00 AM    IN      2015-08-26
123     06:00 PM    OUT     2015-08-26
123     08:00 AM    IN      2015-08-27
123     06:00 PM    OUT     2015-08-27
null    null        null    2015-08-28
null    null        null    2015-08-28
null    null        null    2015-08-29
null    null        null    2015-08-29
null    null        null    2015-08-30
null    null        null    2015-08-30
```

how to make it?

Comment: Do you have a calendar table?

Comment: Would you rather show the `IN` and `OUT` column values for the missing data?  Otherwise, it's just repeated days.

Comment: > Do you have a calendar table? – jarlh I would like to add on to jarlh. If you have a calendar table, you can left join your SQL table onto the calendar table and it will get the output results that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that creates a date-range table and does a `RIGHT JOIN` to it for the missing days:

```
Declare @StartDate  Date = '2015-08-01',
        @EndDate    Date = '2015-08-30'

;With Date (Date) As
(
    Select  @StartDate Union All
    Select  DateAdd(Day, 1, Date)
    From    Date
    Where   Date < @EndDate
),
Keys As
(
    Select  'IN'    As [Key]
    Union All
    Select  'OUT'   As [Key]
),
InOutDates As
(
    Select      Date, [Key]
    From        Date
    Cross Join  Keys
)
Select      E.ID, E.AttTime, E.[Key], D.Date As attDate
From        EmployeeTable   E
Right Join  InOutDates      D   On  D.Date = E.AttDate
                                And E.[Key] = D.[Key]
Option      (MaxRecursion 0)
```

If you want to also select the `IN`/`OUT` values for the `Key` of the missing date, you can use:

```
...
Select      E.ID, E.AttTime, D.[Key], D.Date As attDate 
...
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/028708/1/0) demo.

Comment: Updated query - changed `Left Join` to `Right Join` to correctly pull the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
Declare @start date = '20150801';
Declare @end date = '20150830';

With inc(n) as (
    Select TOP(1+DATEDIFF(day, @start, @end)) ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select 1))-1 
    From (
        Select 1 From (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as x1(n)
        Cross Join (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as x2(n)
    ) as x(n)
)
Select d.ID, d.AttTime, d.key, attDate = DATEADD(day, n, @start) 
From inc
Cross Join (values('IN'), ('OUT')) as k(name)
Left Join yourData as d on d.attDate = DATEADD(day, n, @start) and d.key = k.name;
```

CTE inc create numbers from 0 to n (difference between @start and @end in days) without using recursive CTE.
It then Cross Join all numbers with IN and OUT and create a range of date with IN/OUT. 
It finally Left Join this range with your data

Answer (score -3):

If I get you right, all tuples are available and you just want to execute a range query, right?

Have you tried something like:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE attDate BETWEEN #08/01/2015# AND #08/30/2015#
```